# Why composer don't pull newer package by Caret Version Range?

Tags: composer-php

my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "foo/boo",
    "description": "bar",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.15",
        "bar/foo": "^0.1.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset": {
            "enabled": false
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        },
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "ssh://deployer@gerrit.foo.pl:29418/bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

Composer documentation for [Caret Version Range](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-) says that my version request of `bar/foo` package should works like: >=0.1.0 and < 1.0.0.

But after `composer update` I got version 0.1.0.
My bar/foo package have tags:

```
$ cd /vendor/my-bar-foo-package
$ git tag --list
v0.1.0
v0.2.0
v0.2.1
v0.2.2
```

After chance version request to `"bar/foo": "0.2.2" composer update pull v0.2.2, why "^0.1.0" doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Composer documentation for Caret Version Range says that my version request of bar/foo package should works like: >=0.1.0 and < 1.0.0.

No, it's not:

> For pre-1.0 versions it also acts with safety in mind and treats `^0.3` as `>=0.3.0 <0.4.0`
>
> <sub>https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-</sub>

So it works as expected - `^0.1.0` is equivalent to `>=0.1.0 <0.2.0` and `0.2.2` release does not match this constraint.

Comment: I thought "^0.3" works different than "^0.3.0". Thanks.